# How can I store and hide a .dylib file inside a framework?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, frameworks, dylib

Yesterday I learned how to create a framework after following [this tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/65964/create-a-framework-for-ios). I would like to know how I am able to hide a `.dylib` file inside a framework.
I wish to only expose the header files of course, while the implementation files would be hidden that interface with the `.dylib` file. How can this be done

Comment: As Ray points out in the tutorial, dynamic libraries (.dylib) (other than those provided by Apple) are not supported on iOS.  Any libraries used must be statically linked (.a)

Comment: I bought an SDK which cost me $1031/£637 after negotiating, and now realise that the files contained within are two .dylib files which I wanted to create a framework for. This is obviously not possible now, what is the best way I could go about asking them to change it to a statically linked (.a) file?